# Asking specific questions for three groups of people

Tags: google-forms

Here's my dilemma.

I'm trying to set up a google form for people RSVPing to my cousin's bar mitzvah. There are three events: the service, a dinner, and a party. But not everyone is invited to every event, and we don't want people feeling left out! There are people invited to all three, there are people invited just to the service and party, and there are people invited to just the service.

Is there a way to ask the name of whoever's filling out the survey, and based on that response, ask a different set of questions? I know it's possible to set up a multiple choice question and direct to different pages based on that, but I don't want to have a dropdown list of *everyone's* names on the form. Is it possible to ask for a text input, check it against a master list, and then direct to a set of questions depending on which group they're in?

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

Google Forms doesn't have such feature and can't be extended through add-ons or Google Apps Script.

## Alternatives

Instead of a single form, create

- a form for each required combination
- a web app